# mysql viewer for windows that connects to SSH using a private key and a passphrase

Tags: windows, gratis, database, mysql

I want to connect to a mysql database located on a linux server, through ssh and using private key and a passphrase, from windows 10, I'm looking for a GUI mysql viewer.

- PHPmyadmin won't work in such scenario
- Mysql workbench didn't work, it couldn't connect using a private key for some reason, it has that option but did not work.
- DataGrip works but it's so confusing, I don't know how to use it, to the point that if I need to do something, I'd rather SSH to the server and write SQL

I want something that:

- is free, I'm willing to pay if the software is decent though and the
  price is reasonable (around $50 max, might stretch the budget a bit, and one time purchase)
- As easy to use as [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) which is for mac only , notice how clean the user interface is, notice how you rarely need to type any sql command, which is not the case for datagrip, at least I wasn't able to use it
- Good documentation or/and tutorials, if I get stuck on datagrip I rarely find help
- Should be able to connect through ssh using a private key and a passphrase
- The software should be similar to PHPMyadmin and When I login, the databases should be listed on the left, when I click a database, tables should be listed
- Extra point: decent community, preferably on stackoverflow

Dbvis is too expensive, I'm going to try [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) and see if it works, I want to know what other options do I have? Because it seems that HeidiSQL  is my only  option now.

**Edit:** Heidisql is prompting me to enter my passphrase but there's no input field, so I can't connect, unless this bug can be fixed, I'll have to find another software.

Comment: @Josem Heidisql is prompting me to enter my passphrase but there's no input field, so I can't connect, unless this bug can be fixed, I'll have to find another software.

Comment: when are you requested to enter the passphrase?

Comment: @Josem after pressing "open" it tries to connect to the server but I get https://imgur.com/a/kMXBzm3 and there's no input field to enter my passphrase. there's only the okay button

Comment: Connect using your key and set up a tunnel - do this with `Putty.exe` - then connect to the SQL server using MySQL Workbench in the normal manner, specifying localhost and whatever port you are forwarding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) free edition, it has pretty much all I asked for. If anyone has a better answer, I'll accept his answer.